# Can I use flow to update multiple items?

Tags: designer-workflow, flow

Is it possible to use flow to update multiple items?
I would like it to loop through items and  update all the Fields.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use Get Items action and filter results to get items you want to update. And then iterate through that collection with Apply to Each loop.

Comment: Thanks Marek for your response.But what should i be selecting as a trigger?
Should it be For a selected items???
To retrieve items i know i can use the get items actions . Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: In Get Items you can filter what you can get so it would be up to you to define the query which items you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link very resourceful on learning how to use Flow.   I know use Flow for multiple SP sites.  The connector has to have access to each SP site to update multiple fields.  I have one Flow that updates multiple items in multiple sites after using Get Item.

**Learning:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/automate-process-using-flow/

**SP Connector:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks JRossi would have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate the list items without any event on any of the existing item in the same list then you can use Scheduled cloud flow.
[Run Flows on a schedule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks)